# Induction: show that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{2^k} = 2 - \frac{n+2}{2^n}$ for all n $\in Z_+$

Tags: induction

**So the question in my textbook is:**

Show by induction that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{2^k} = 2 - \frac{n+2}{2^n}$ for all $n$ $\in Z_+$.

**My attempt at a solution:**

First of all $Z_+ = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ...$

So I start to make sure that the base case is right... For that I choose $k = 1$

This gives us:

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^1 \frac{1}{2^1} = 2 - \frac{1+2}{2^1} \rightarrow \frac{1}{2} = 2 - \frac{3}{2}$$

The base case does work.

The next step is to take make the inductive assumption that it is true for $n = k$. This gives us:

$$\frac{1}{2^1} + \frac{2}{2^2} + ... +  \frac{k}{2^k}  = 2 - \frac{k+2}{2^k}$$

The next step is to show that $n = k + 1$ holds:

$$\frac{1}{2^1} + \frac{2}{2^2} + ... +  \frac{k}{2^k} + \frac{k+1}{2^{k+1}}  = 2 - \frac{k+1+2}{2^{k+1}}$$

By using the induction hypothesis we have:

$$\frac{1}{2^1} + \frac{2}{2^2} + ... +  \frac{k}{2^k} + \frac{k+1}{2^{k+1}}  = 2 - \frac{k+2}{2^k} + \frac{k+1}{2^{k+1}}$$

The $RHS$ can be written as: 
$$2 - \frac{k+2}{2^{k}} + \frac{k+1}{2^{k+1}}$$

How do I move on from here and show that:

$$2 - \frac{k+2}{2^{k}} + \frac{k+1}{2^{k+1}} = 2 - \frac{k+1+2}{2^{k+1}}$$

Thank you!

Comment: Is the expression supposed to be $0$ ?

Comment: I don't know @ClaudeLeibovici , This is the only information I have, in the answers to the question it only says "use standard procedure"...

Comment: Then, what is doing the $=$ sign for your attempt for $n=1$ ?

Comment: @LukasArvidsson I think you have a typo. The minus sign in $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{2^k}2 - \frac{n+2}{2^n}$ should be replaced with an equal sign: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{2^k}2 = \frac{n+2}{2^n}$ maybe?

Comment: Oh yes! There is actually a minus sign in my textbook so It is probably a typo there! Thank you so much for your help! This solves it (I hope)

Comment: @LukasArvidsson Actually I take that back. Keep the minus sign. I think the real typo is an omitted equals sign before the 2: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{2^k}=2 - \frac{n+2}{2^n}$

Comment: @LukasArvidsson. I think it would be nice you also establish the formula. It is simple.

Comment: This type of sum is called a [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By induction, it is quite easy : just add the $(n+1)$ term if the lhs and in the rhs independently (to this one, substract the value of the sum for $n$). You will see, after very simple simplifications, that these two terms are equal.

Now, how to establish this formula ? Look at the term in the summation as $k x^k$. This is $x$ times the derivative of $x^k$; that is to say that you have to sum from $k=1$ to $k=n$ terms which are in geometric progression; you know the formula for the sum. So, compute the derivative of the sum, multiple the result by $x$ and .... plug $x=1/2$. Then, manipulate a little and you get it.

Comment: Hi @ClaudeLeibovici I have trouble with showing that the these two terms are equal: $2 - \frac{k+2}{2^{k}} + \frac{k+1}{2^{k+1}} = 2 - \frac{k+1+2}{2^{k+1}}$ (please look at updated question if you want to know how I derived these terms) Have I done something wrong? Thank you VERY much for your help! Much appreciated!

Comment: @LukasArvidsson.First replace $k$ by $n$. But you made a mistake since the difference of the two consecutive rhs's is : 2 - (n+3)/2^(n+1) - 2 + (n+2)/2^n = 2 (n+2) / 2^(n+1) - (n+3) / 2^(n+1) = (n + 1) / 2^(n+1). QED. By the way, if you like my answer, you can accept it.

Comment: Thank you Claude for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think that what they ask you is to show that

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{2^k}- (2 - \frac{n+2}{2^n}) = 0$

Comment: Hi Claude! As stated by David H, there is probably a typo in my textbook and the question probably is: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{2^k}=2 - \frac{n+2}{2^n}$

Comment: No ! You just repeat the typo. What David H suggested does not work for $n=1$. I suppose my assumption is correct.

Comment: @LukasArvidsson Listen to Claude! My first suggestion was wrong. See my second comment above.

Comment: @DavidH. Now, it seems that we agree. It is quite easy to show that this equality works. Cheers.

Comment: Your are correct @ClaudeLeibovici. If someone is lazy... http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+n%2F2%5En+from+1+to+m

Comment: By the way, should not the OP correct the question?

Comment: Hi @Umberto I have corrected the question, but still need some help to finish it...

Comment: @Umberto. It takes a few seconds to do it by hand. If you want to know how, just post. Cheers.

Comment: Hi @ClaudeLeibovici! please show it if you have the time. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It works in this way. Consider this (I will skip some passages to make the answer shorter, but they should be easy enough).
$$
S(x)=\sum_{k=1}^nkx^k
$$
we are interested in $S(1/2)$.
Now is easy to see that
$$
kx^k=x\frac{d}{dx}x^k
$$
so we can write
$$
S(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n x\frac{d}{dx}x^k=x \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=1}^n x^k
$$
but 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n x^k = \frac{x(x^n-1)}{x-1}
$$
so taking the derivative of this sum we get
$$
S(x)=x\frac{nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^n+1}{(x-1)^2}
$$
Now we can calculate $S(1/2)$ and we get
$$
S(1/2) = \frac{1}{2}\left( 2\frac{n}{2^n} - 4\frac{n+1}{2^n} +4\right)
$$
and if you simplify this you get your result. I hope you can complete the missing passage. That is only algebra.

Comment: Thank you very much Umberto for your answer, much appreciated!